# unable to receive data on server side in socket communication

Tags: c, sockets, client, server

I have following codes. I want to do multicast socket communication. I am able to send data from server to no of clients but at the same time i want to receive data from clients. I want to do in like group chat. But when i insert `read()` or `recvfrom()` server stops executing. So i thought of adding it to the Group IP which has done on client side. But it did not help.. Any suggestions.. ?

Server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd,len,n=0;
char databuf[1024]; //= "Multicast test message lol!";
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);

int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");
    /* Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a */
   /* group address of 225.1.1.1 and port 5555. */
    len=sizeof(groupSock);
    memset(&groupSock, 0, len);
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(4321);

   /* Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams. */
   /* The IP address specified must be associated with a local, */
    /* multicast capable interface. */
    localInterface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;//inet_addr("10.99.92.101");

    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Setting local interface error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");

    {
        perror("bind error");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter data for clients: ");
        scanf("%s",databuf);
        if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
            {perror("Sending datagram message error");}
            else
            printf("Sending datagram message...OK\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");
    /* Enable SO_REUSEADDR to allow multiple instances of this */
        /* application to receive copies of the multicast datagrams. */
    {
        int reuse = 1;
        if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");
    }
    /* Bind to the proper port number with the IP address */
    /* specified as INADDR_ANY. */
    memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
    {
        perror("Binding datagram socket error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");
    /* Join the multicast group 226.1.1.1 on the local */
    /* interface. Note that this IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option must be */
    /* called for each local interface over which the multicast */
    /* datagrams are to be received. */
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("226.1.1.1");
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Adding multicast group error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");
    /* Read from the socket. */
    while(1)
    {
        datalen = sizeof(databuf);

        if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
        {
            perror("Reading datagram message error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
            printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
        }   
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your code , but I can't send a message from the client to the server at all. I have included errno.h and  your piece of code below gave me an error "Transport endpoint is not connected" . So your question is confusing, you are saying that you are able to send data from server to no of clients? But his code isn't doing that?Please be more specific.

```
  int n;
  n = write(sd,databuf,datalen);

  if(n == -1) printf("writing error %s\n",strerror(errno);
```

Comment: updated the code! Its working now... I mean this is sending messages to multiple clients... But now i want to receive the messages from the clients... What changes  should i do ??